# Use post request to receive LinkedIn user profile information in iOS

Tags: ios, post, linkedin-api

I am looking for a way to retrieve the profile information of a LinkedIn user by making a post request, I have read these two LinkedIn pages but it doesn't seem to explain much, or I couldn't understand much of it:

[REST API LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq)
[basic profile informations](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

I have seen these example on stackoverflow but I didn't understood to much:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,location:(country:(code)),industry,distance,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,date-of-birth,main-address,positions:(title),educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))
```

I am only interested to retrieve the skills section the one that on the website appears as so:

[image]

Comment: Tried to use: @"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(skills)"  but it returns an empty string

Answer (score 1):

There's a fantastic library for LinkedIn-iOS integration by [Kirsten Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1112693/kirsten-jones), you can use that to make calls to the LinkedIn API. You need an access token to make calls.

https://github.com/PrincessPolymath/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client

Make calls like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,location:(country:(code)),industry,distance,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,date-of-birth,main-address,positions:(title),educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))"]];
    OAMutableURLRequest *request = 
    [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                    consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                       token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                    callback:nil
                           signatureProvider:nil];

    [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFinish:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFail:)];    

- (void)profileApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data 
{
    NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *profile = [responseBody objectFromJSONString];

    if ( profile )
    {
        name.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                     [profile objectForKey:@"firstName"], [profile objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
        headline.text = [profile objectForKey:@"headline"];

        .....and get skills and other user details

     }    
}
```

Comment: but where do I add the username? also is a password required?

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking about a user's linkedin account. The library has the view that pushes the view to ask username and password. Once you get the permission you can then make these calls

Comment: when I run the project it asks for authentication

Comment: That's when you get your accessToken. The library does it automatically for you. Just use it

Comment: The Kristen Jones  library is full of Bugs and issues, and is normal since it was build a few years ago, Thanks anyway

Comment: I have used a different one and the problem is that by using the upper link, the JSON returned doesn't contain the aptitudes .

Comment: Ok I have tried the link witch you suggested but it doesn't also return Skills & Endorsements, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use tool:https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

API to get the list of Skills:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,skills)?format=json

I tried it in the Console tool and able to fetch the skills for my profile. I think the individual skill ID with above request should help you to get further information. Try it out.

Comment: Ok so apparently the error were given because I have made a type-o , and after the call the returned result is: {
    id = eOZWq36nxC;
    numConnections = 99;
}

Comment: Will this help to build the app?

Comment: No, because it doesn't return what it should return... And I have tags set up on my profile in the skills and endorsment section

Comment: When I searched around this I observed that this is still in evolving phase. Do you know any application which does this? If so then I may be help.

Comment: Here is the "issue" that I opened on the github page of the tool that I am using: https://github.com/PrincessPolymath/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client/issues/12

Answer (score 1):

I have fair amount of experience working with the linkedIn API. It's been a little while, but hopefully this will set you on the right track.

To get profile information from a linked in user *who is one of your connections* you need a format like follows:

```
NSString *theRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=abc123:(first-name,last-name,picture-url,location:(name))?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken];
```

This request will return the first name, last name, profile picture url, and location of the user with the id specified.

You can see a list of field types you can request by checking out linkedIn's documentation on their profile field descriptions here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields

If you're wondering how to get the id of the user whose profile information you want request in the first place, you can make request for some basic info (including ids) of all your connections like this:

```
NSString *basicConnectionInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken];
```

This request will give you the id, first name, and last name of all of your connections. After you've gotten the id of the person you want, you can make a request using the user's id (as shown in the first example).

Now for the slightly unfortunately news... If you followed the link provided above, you'll notice that the *skills* field is part of the "Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers". I'm assuming you'll have to follow this link they provided: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin in order to access the *skills* member profile field.

I have not applied with LinkedIn. So, I haven't tested a call to the *skills* field. But, I'm guessing it'll be similar to the examples I've shown you. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is reading this answer, the LinkedIn API has limited access as of May 2015. You will need to apply to their Apply with LinkedIn program to access full profile fields including skills.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields